# What's the difference between these two functions

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

So i have an json array named users. Im trying to update an individual field if id comes from request equals to users id. When i use for loop it works but it doesn't when i try to use forEach (there are no errors). I don't understand the difference between these two. [image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `forEach`, `user` is just a variable that happens to start with the value passed in as a parameter to your lambda function. Setting `user = ...` doesn't actually change anything in the original array. Nor does it change the properties on the object that is currently in that array.

Consider using `Object.assign()` instead:

```
Object.assign(user, req.body);
```

Comment: Thank you so much !